# Getting the hash of a file

Tags: angular, typescript, ts-md5

From a `FormModel`, I am retrieving the `File` that I uploaded from the UI.

Now, I need to get the `Hash` of the `File` object. How can I do this ?

The package i am using is [ts-md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-md5).

In the sample code given , First the file needs to saved as a `blob` and then it's taken to Hash it.

```
import {ParallelHasher} from 'ts-md5/dist/parallel_hasher';

let hasher = new ParallelHasher('/path/to/ts-md5/dist/md5_worker.js');
hasher.hash(fileBlob).then(function(result) {
   console.log('md5 of fileBlob is', result);
});
```

However, in my case, I need to calculate the hash without saving it to a blob. How can I do this ?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), a `File` _is_ a `Blob`.  Did you try passing your `File` directly to `hasher.hash`?